# ETE2 .phonehome() Is it an Easter Egg?

Tags: python, messaging, etetoolkit

[ETE2](http://ete.cgenomics.org/) (a Python Environment for phylogenetic Tree Exploration) has a method `.phonehome()` which can be called on tree/node class objects. This returns:

```
== Calling home... Got answer!

He11o alien,
How is everything in the Earth?
We miss you in Brodo Asogi.

I see you are in shape.
No updates are available.

== Do you want to leave any message?
(Press enter to finish)
```

If you want to test this for yourself, try:

```
from ete2 import Tree
t = Tree()      # generate random Tree
t.phonehome()   # communicate with Aliens!
```

Is this an easter egg?

Comment: What else would it be? I note that the project uses the iconic ET flying-cycle-silhouette as the logo.

Comment: a real alien trying to communicate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [project logo](http://ete.cgenomics.org/) is:

[image: ETE2 logo]

So you could call it an easter egg. But it also has a real purpose, as it is the projects version check method, named with a pinch of humor:

```
''' I use this module to check for newer versions of ETE '''
```

and

```
def call():
    print "  == Calling home...",
    try:
        f = url.urlopen('http://ete.cgenomics.org/et_phone_home.php?VERSION=%s&ID=%s' 
                %(__VERSION__, __ETEID__))
```

and:

```
if not latest:
    print "I could not find data about your version [%s]" %module_name
    print "Are you ok?"
elif not current:
    print "I could not determine your version [%s]" %module_name
    print "Are you ok?"
    print "Latest stable ETE version is", latest
elif latest > current:
    print "You look a bit old."
    print "A newer version is available: rev%s" %latest
    print "Use 'easy_install -U %s' to upgrade" %module_name
else:
    print "I see you are in shape."
    print "No updates are available."
```

See the [source code of the `ete2._ph` module](https://github.com/jhcepas/ete/blob/master/ete_dev/_ph.py); [`phonehome()` calls `ete2._ph.call()`](https://github.com/jhcepas/ete/blob/master/ete_dev/coretype/tree.py#L2099-L2101).